# Have a method call another method within a function component

Tags: reactjs, jsx, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I am using a component called [DocumentPicker](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/pickers) from the Fluent UI library.

This components has several methods:

```
<DocumentPicker
    removeButtonAriaLabel="Remove"
    onRenderSuggestionsItem={SuggestedBigItem as any}
    onResolveSuggestions={ /* do some stuff here */ }
    onRenderItem={SelectedDocumentItem}
    getTextFromItem={getTextFromItem}
    pickerSuggestionsProps={pickerSuggestionsProps}
    disabled={isPickerDisabled}
    inputProps={inputProps}
  />
```

For my specific scenario, I'd like to have a method of this component call another method. For example, have onEmptyInputFocus trigger onResolveSuggestions. How can I accomplish this?

[edit] Basically I am trying to accomplish with a function component what I would be able to do using "this" on a class component. In my class component I could write something like:

```
  public onEmptyInputFocus () {this.onResolveSuggestions();}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you specify these methods, it's pretty easy:

```
const _onEmptyInputFocus = () => {
  onResolveSuggestions()
}

<DocumentPicker
    removeButtonAriaLabel="Remove"
    onEmptyInputFocus={_onEmptyInputFocus}
    onRenderSuggestionsItem={SuggestedBigItem as any}
    onResolveSuggestions={onFilterChanged}
    onRenderItem={SelectedDocumentItem}
    getTextFromItem={getTextFromItem}
    pickerSuggestionsProps={pickerSuggestionsProps}
    disabled={isPickerDisabled}
    inputProps={inputProps}
  />
```

Comment: I must be missing something, this gives me an error as I would expect. There is no onResolveSuggestions function in my code. Also, I think I get your point but there won't always be parity between method and function. Let me update my question to make it more clear.

Comment: Im having trouble with the context of where you want to trigger these methods, is it in a different component?

Comment: It's the same component. I am trying to make my scenario work without having to rewrite the component. In a class component I would use "this" to call internal methods from another method but I can't figure out the equivalent in function components.

Answer (score 0):

I think I am pretty clear now that it cannot be accomplished with function components. You would have to know the internals of the component and tweak it.

A workaround is to use a ref and work with the underlying HTML element. In Fluent UI the prop is actually called componentRef, not just ref.